# Ruby on rails order loop by date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, loops, range

I have been having problems with figuring out how to create a simple loop that has a date range condition.

here is my video controller

```
def index
    @videos = Video.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
end
```

I am trying to only loop out videos in my view that are no older then one month from the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@videos = Video.
  where(created_at: 1.month.ago.to_date..Date.current).
  order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
```